# How to Convert a datetime to Long Date?

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

Below is my code,

```
DateTime DateFrom_ = Convert.ToDateTime(CSO.dateFrom);
```

I am getting the value currently like - 29/10/2019 00:00:00
what i want is I want to convert above to this format - Tue, 29 Oct 2019

can anyone please guide me how to do this, Thank you.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `long date`. Dates are binary values, they have no format. What you typed is a *string*. Use `DateTime.ToString()` with the correct format specifier

Comment: Look at [`DateTime.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_) / [`ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) and [`DateTime.ToString(format)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_)

Comment: Also see [Standard DateTime Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [Custom DateTime Formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Use `DateTime.Now.ToString("D")` to get a string in your culture's long date format.

Comment: You can also use `DateTime.ToLongDateString()` which is just a shortcut to `ToString("D")`

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd', 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy");`

Comment: Note that it's normally best to use the standard formats (like `D`) rather than specific ones (like `ddd, dd MMM yyyy`), as the former will adjust to each locale's preferred format, whereas the latter might look weird in other locales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below one worked for me,

```
DateTime DateFrom_ = Convert.ToDateTime(CSO.dateFrom);    
var convertedDate = DateFrom_.ToString("ddd', 'dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily, using `DateTime.ParseExact` to parse from certain format, and then use `ToString` with different format to represent it based on your need:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("29/10/2019 00:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
date.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy"); // output Tue, 29 Oct 2019
```

Please note, if you need culture specific long date representation, then you should use `ToString("D", cultureInfo)` overload. That way, your format will be aligned with the culture defined format.

Comment: The OP isn't asking about *parsing*

Comment: @Panagiotis The way I read the question, they are asking both about parsing and formatting. They want to take a string in one format, and convert it to another format. Of course, the question is unclear and this is an assumption. That's why the question contains `Convert.ToDateTime`

Answer (score 0):

I think using `DateTime.ToString()` with the specific format should do the work. Try this one:

```
date.ToString("D", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's been mentioned in here, you want to be using "DateTime.ParseExact"

```
  var str = "Tue, 29 Oct 2019";
  var date = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may split the date and use DateTime.ParseExact.

```
 string[] tokens = "29/10/2019 00:00:00".Split(' ');
    DateTime DateFrom_ =  DateTime.ParseExact(tokens[0], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

 var dateString = DateFrom_.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy");
```

Comment: Why would you do this, rather than parsing the whole string?